# JavaScript : How to inspect break point values in Chrome Debugger tools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, javascript-debugger

I have this simple a js file , which prints date continosly .

I am using Google Chrome Debugger tools (F12)

I have set a break point at the line  `s = date.getSeconds();`

It has stopped at that break point .

My question is can i see/inspect the break point value??(if its eclipse,iwould have used **Ctrl + Shift + i**)

**I know about the console option , but can i see value on the debugger  tool ??**

please see the screen shot here .

[image]

Thanks in advance .

```
function date_time(id)
{
        date = new Date;
        year = date.getFullYear();
        month = date.getMonth();
        months = new Array('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'Jully', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December');
        d = date.getDate();
        day = date.getDay();
        days = new Array('Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday');
        h = date.getHours();
        if(h<10)
        {
                h = "0"+h;
        }
        m = date.getMinutes();
        if(m<10)
        {
                m = "0"+m;
        }
        s = date.getSeconds();
        if(s<10)
        {
                s = "0"+s;
        }
        result = ''+days[day]+' '+months[month]+' '+d+' '+year+' '+h+':'+m+':'+s;
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = result;
        setTimeout('date_time("'+id+'");','1000');
        return true;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can

- hover with the mouse over the interested variables
- open the "Scope Variables" section on the right sidebar
- open the console ("Press Esc") and type in the variable to see its value

For instance:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much  hover with mouse i was looking for .

Answer (score 2):

select break point variable 's' and right click on selected 's' and choose option add to watch 
then u can see  s value in right side of Chrome Debugger window and press F10 to dibug next line.